# 301 Redirects on any non existent image, pdf or url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website that is constantly updated and the problem is that the Google bot that indexes the website gives a lot of 404/500 errors when a image does not exist anymore or has been deleted. It's a product catalogue website, so products get deleted and added on a hourly basis.

I've tried this RewriteRule

```
^/(.*)$ /site/page/view/404 [R=301,L]
```

which causes all images on the website not to display any more or

```
^(.*) /site/page/view/404 [R=301,L]
```

which just gives error 500 on the browser.

Is there a way to match non existent files/urls and redirect them permanently to different url e.g. `/site/page/view/404`

Answer (score 2):

Try this *(assuming `.htaccess` is in web root)*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # not a dir    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # not a file
RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/page/view/404 [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, you can use `ErrorDocument` as well.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /site/page/view/404
```

Comment: @Ravi - Thanks for the answer, I've tried errordocument, but all I get then is a default browser message saying Oops, page not found. When I try the RewriteRule RewriteRule ^.*$ /site/page/view/404 [R=301,L] I get a chrome message This webpage has a redirect loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Does "/site/page/view/404" physically exist? Can you reach it by typing it directly in the browser?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal - Yes it exist